# Unitary operators evolving the set of Pauli matrices

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, vectors, notation

Consider the Heisenberg picture of Quantum Mechanics. For a two state system we have the Pauli matrices evolving according to the relation $$\sigma_i(t)=U^+\sigma_i(0)U$$ where $U=e^{-iHt/\hbar}$ and $i=x,y,z.$

But in a particular research paper I saw the evolution written as $$\vec\sigma(t)=U^+\vec\sigma(0)U$$ where $\vec\sigma=(\sigma_x,\sigma_y,\sigma_z)$. Thinking about the matrix representation of this equation, it is a 2x2 matrix $U^+$ multiplied by a 3x1 matrix  $\vec\sigma$  multiplied by a 2x2 matrix $U$ which is obviously wrong. Where am I making mistakes in interpreting the above equation?

Comment: the second expression is just a funny way to write the first one (which is the one that is right)

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-f2WgH6tfE-UGtZZUNmdWNwM1U and https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-f2WgH6tfE-bXFWdVRRSTVRY0k. This is the context in which I saw the above equation. Specifically, equation (3) in the second link.

Comment: $\vec{\sigma}$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix, $\sigma_x \vec{e}_x + \sigma_y \vec{e}_y + \sigma_z \vec{e}_z$.

Comment: @auxsvr towards the end of the paragraph in the second link they are talking about $\sigma_{ij}$..what does the i and j stand for in this?

Comment: $\sigma_{ij}$ is the $i,j$-th element of the matrix $\vec{\sigma}$. A common convention is to interpret $i$ as the row and $j$ as the column.

Comment: @auxsvr But $\vec\sigma$ has only three elements right? It is a column vector, right?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-f2WgH6tfE-VzUyOHEwZ1lHX0E. This is the equation for $\sigma_{ij}$ that they write just after the content of the previous two links. So what are the possible values of  i and j in this equation. Because $\vec\sigma$ is a column matrix i=1 and j=1,2,3, right?

Comment: For example, $\vec{\sigma}_{11}$ is $\vec{e}_z$. Probably, the notation confuses you because you interpret $\vec{e}_i$ in terms of coordinates. Vectors are elements of a vector space and it is an extra step to assign coordinates to them. The vector spaces where $\vec{e}_i$ and $\sigma_{i}$ belong are _not_ the same in general!

Comment: @RajathKrishnaR note that in your link it says $\vec\sigma_{ij}$, not $\sigma_{ij}$. So this notation uses the vector as explained in my answer below, but chooses to write out the 2 indices here called i,j of the Pauli matrices themselves instead of leaving them as matrix objects.

Comment: @Numrok Sorry for asking again but I'm actually very confused about this notation. So can you write down what, for example $\vec\sigma_{ij}$ corresponds to explicitly.,....

Comment: Check Frobenius's answer below, it's more explicit. Does the paper define $\vec{\sigma} = (\sigma_x, \sigma_y, \sigma_z)$?

Comment: http://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0511021v2.pdf ..this is the paper.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take your first relation for the 3 Pauli matrices individually:

$$\sigma_1(t)=U^\dagger\sigma_1(0)U$$

$$\sigma_1(t)=U^\dagger\sigma_2(0)U$$

$$\sigma_3(t)=U^\dagger\sigma_3(0)U$$

Now you define a "vector" for notational convenience like the OP says in the question. I will choose to rewrite it as a column vector to visually show the relation of the above 3 relations:
 \begin{equation}
     \vec\sigma=
     \begin{pmatrix}
          \sigma_x\\
          \sigma_y\\
          \sigma_z
        \end{pmatrix}
  \end{equation}

Now we can write the above 3 notations as: $$\vec\sigma(t)=U^\dagger\vec\sigma(0)U$$

What we have really done here is define a new product that acts on the vectors defined for notational convenience. It acts as follows:

\begin{equation}
     U
     \begin{pmatrix}
          \sigma_x\\
          \sigma_y\\
          \sigma_z
        \end{pmatrix}
:=  \begin{pmatrix}
          U \sigma_x\\
          U \sigma_y\\
          U \sigma_z
        \end{pmatrix}
  \end{equation}

Note this is a *definition* for notational convenience and there is nothing physical about it.

Comment: This notation can be used even if the coefficient matrices are linearly dependent!

Comment: @auxsvr thanks good point! i edited my answer. i guess i was anticipating that we could define other products

Answer (score 2):

If $\mathbf{x}=\left(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}\right)$ is a 3-vector rotated to  $\mathbf{x}^{\prime}=\left(x_{1}^{\prime},x_{2}^{\prime},x_{3}^{\prime}\right)$  then this rotation is expressed via special unitary matrices  $U \in SU\left(2\right)$ as follows :

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{X}^{\prime}\equiv
  \begin{bmatrix}         
         x^{'}_3&x^{'}_1-ix^{'}_2\\
         x^{'}_1+ix^{'}_2&-x^{'}_3
   \end{bmatrix}
=U
  \begin{bmatrix}         
         x_3&x_1-ix_2\\
         x_1+ix_2&-x_3
   \end{bmatrix}
U^{*}
=U\mathbf{X}U^{*}
\tag{01}
\end{equation}
So, I think that we must consider $\boldsymbol{\sigma}=\left(\sigma_{1},\sigma_{2},\sigma_{3}\right)$ typically as a 3-vector and interpret equation as follows :

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\mathbf{\Sigma}\left(t\right)& \equiv
  \begin{bmatrix}         
         \sigma_{3}\left(t\right) & \sigma_{1}\left(t\right)-i\sigma_{2}\left(t\right)\\
         \sigma_{1}\left(t\right)+i\sigma_{2}\left(t\right) &-\sigma_{3}\left(t\right)
   \end{bmatrix}
=U
  \begin{bmatrix}         
         \sigma_{3}\left(0\right) & \sigma_{1}\left(0\right)-i\sigma_{2}\left(0\right)\\
         \sigma_{1}\left(0\right)+i\sigma_{2}\left(t\right) &-\sigma_{3}\left(0\right)
   \end{bmatrix}
U^{*}\\
&=U\mathbf{\Sigma}\left(0\right)U^{*}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
------------------------------
\tag{02}
\end{equation}

Note that if $\mathbb{A}$ is the $3\times3$ rotation matrix from which the special unitary matrix $U$ or $-U$ is created then typically :

\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{\sigma}\left(t\right)\equiv
 \begin{bmatrix}         
        \sigma_{1}\left(t\right)\\
        \sigma_{2}\left(t\right)\\
        \sigma_{3}\left(t\right)
   \end{bmatrix}
=\mathbb{A}
 \begin{bmatrix}         
        \sigma_{1}\left(0\right)\\
        \sigma_{2}\left(0\right)\\
        \sigma_{3}\left(0\right)
  \end{bmatrix}
=\mathbb{A}\boldsymbol{\sigma}\left(0\right)
\tag{03}
\end{equation}

Comment: Why does the elements of X have that particular form? Like why is the second element in first row $x_1-ix_2$?

Comment: @Rajath Krishna R : May be you must enjoy with the details to pass from a rotation equation expressed with real 3-vectors and real orthonormal $3\times3$ rotation matrix, like equation (03) in my answer, to the corresponding equation with $2\times2$ complex matrices, like equation (01).

Comment: The paper mixes two conventions and probably defines $\vec{\sigma}(t) = \sigma_1(t)  \vec{e}_1 + \sigma_2(t) \vec{e}_2 + \sigma_3(t) \vec{e}_3$, where the vector space is defined by the Pauli matrices, i.e. $\vec{e}_1 = \sigma_x$, etc.